# JavaScript: Reading image with html form und zip the data

Tags: javascript, binary, zip

I have a problem and can't figure out how to solve it.
I'm reading image data via a html form in the browser. At this point, I have the binary data in the input array.
Now I have to send this image to the server. Before I transfer this image over the internet, I would like to compress it.
Do you know any way to handle this?

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests

Comment: Do you know how to compress only the image read with the html form?